# Pin Icons to right side of Windows Taskbar?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, pinning

How can I pin a program/folder to the right side of the taskbar, instead of the left side?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: When you say "pin" are you talking about just having the icon available on the right side? Or do you mean add it to the tool tray on the right side? Just asking because a lot of people mix up the two. :)

Comment: when you right click on an icon, you have the option to "pin to taskbar" isn't it? and when you do that it will be pinned at the leftmost available position in the taskbar. I want it to be pinned at the rightmost available position

Comment: Correct! I do not think you can do this. The best solution you could do is right-click on the toolbar, then go to Toolbars at the top. That menu has an item named New Toolbar. You can select any folder and all items in the folder will appear under a single button on the toolbar. I would be really interested in some tool that could do what you want though.

Comment: As Thraka said, the closest you can get to this is by [restoring the Quick Launch toolbar](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975784), which will be right-justified by default.

Comment: @Thraka : No need for any tool. It's very simple trick you can do easily. Just check my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create a **New Folder** anywhere in your computer and then follow the given below steps:

1. Right click on **Taskbar** -> **Toolbars** -> **New toolbars...**
2. Select **New Folder** and click **Select Folder**
3. Right click **Taskbar** -> **Lock the taskbar** (uncheck)

Now your taskbar is unlocked and you will see markers (3 dotted vertical lines) on left and right. Now again follow the given below steps:

1. Select marker on right side and drag it to near your start button.
2. Right click on **New Folder** -> **Show title** (uncheck)
3. Right click **Taskbar** -> **Lock the taskbar** (check)

Now your taskbar is locked and all programs are aligned to right side.

Here is a screenshot to better understand:

[image: Pin Icons to right side of Windows Taskbar]

Comment: also working in windows 10 v1709

Comment: @intlawlisover9000 it works on all windows versions including Windows 7, Windows 8 and WIndows 10