# How to pin some icons to the left side and rest to the right side of the taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

How to pin half of the icons to the left side and the rest of the icons to the right side of the taskbar in Windows 10?

Like on this image:

[image: As shown here]

Comment: I don't understand the question.  What I see is pinned shortcuts and icons in the taskbar, two very different things, in the Windows world.

Comment: @Ramhound As you can see in the image the icon of Visual Studio is on the right side, rest all icons are on the left side. How to achieve something like that

Comment: You click and drag the icons?

Comment: @Ramhound I clicked and dragged to take the screenshot. But how to achieve a permanent look like that

Comment: I don't understand.  You asked how to do it. You drag the icons to the position you want, once you do that, their location is remembered.  Honestly I am attempting to drag the icons before the `show hidden icon` icon and I can't do it myself, so I am not even sure, how you did that one icon.

Comment: yeah I know it is possible to arrange the icons but how to keep it far right and rest of them to left

Comment: We are not talking about the shortcuts being on the "left" correct?  I will repeat I have no idea how you got the single icon to appear before the `show hidden icons` icon, but you should be able to just arrange the icons, by moving them.

Comment: Check my old answer, you can pin wherever you want left right or center, just doing a simple trick http://superuser.com/questions/507392/pin-icons-to-right-side-of-windows-taskbar

Comment: Holy Canoli @VikasPatidar That actually works. You're a genius! I've used the toolbar thingy for my desktop items for years, but never considered it for this application. This question is officially a duplicate and should be closed as such. Rico, check our Vikas' answer. It works in Win10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pin Icons to right side of Windows Taskbar?](http://superuser.com/questions/507392/pin-icons-to-right-side-of-windows-taskbar)

Comment: @music2myear Thanks :) I think OP is asking a little bit different than what I answered in previous question. However we can do it same way but its little bit tricky. Please check here is what I have answered to OP http://superuser.com/a/1173893/60269

Answer (score 4):

Create a new folder anywhere in your computer and paste all those shortcuts you wants to pin on the right side.

Now right click on Taskbar => Toolbars => New toolbar...

Now select the folder where your all shortcuts are.

Now right click the Taskbar and unselect "Lock the taskbar"

Now right click on newly added toolbar and unselect "Show text" and "Show title" repeatedly.

Now again right click on taskbar toolbar => View => Large icons

Now again lock the taskbar and you are done.

Here is what I did:

[image]

Comment: The only problem is, now we have the same answer in two places for two questions. By marking this question as a duplicate, we direct people (and OP) to the location where the answer is given once correctly. It helps keep the site from bloating. I don't know when the question will get closed, but when it does, we'll get it all pointed over to your correct and accepted answer.

Comment: @music2myear   In the other question, it was far less clear that it was achieving pinning on both left and right.

Comment: This can only be done on the primary screen right?

Answer (score -1):

The ones on the left are the *taskbar*.
The ones on the right are the *system tray*.

Typically only certain apps can be pinned to the system tray.  To access: Click Windows icon. Type *Select Which Icons Appear on the Taskbar* and click it. Drag the slider to on or off for those that are listed to show/hide them.

You can go a step further and Windows icon > *Turn system icons on or off* and have more options there.

Comment: actually I don't want to show it on the system tray. I want it to be as like shown in the picture.

Answer (score -1):

Rico, I was having the same issue.  Here are the simple steps to get it to display exactly as you've shown in your image:
1. Right click the windows icon.
2. Left click "Control Panel".
3. Left click "Appearance and Personalization".
4. Left click "Taskbar and Navigation".
5. Where it says "Taskbar Location on Screen", scroll down and select "Bottom".

Baam, easy cheezy!

Comment: This is not what OP is asking. Please carefully read the question before answering. OP wants some of his pinned icons to show at the right side of the taskbar. Your answer is about the location of the taskbar on the screen which is NOT the same thing.